# Moving Files between Folders with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

I'm trying to write a function which will allow me move .xlsm files between folders. I'm aware I can use shutil.move(), however, I'm trying to build a function that will take a file path as a parameter/argument and then perform the procedure.

Here's what I have:

```
def FileMove(source):

  import os
  import shutil 

  source = 'C:\\Users\\FolderB\\'
  archive = 'C:\\Users\\FolderA\\' 

  UsedFiles = os.listdir(source)


  for file in UsedFiles:
     shutil.move(source+file, archive)
```

This doesn't do anything. Just wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction

Cheers

Comment: Your ``source`` argument is shadowed by the local variable. You should remove/rename either one. Also, when joining paths please use ``os.path.join(...)`` as it is much saver this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just delete `def FileMove(source):` and it works fine.
Or you do something like that:

```
import os
import shutil

def FileMove(source):

    archive = 'C:\\Users\\FolderA\\' 

    UsedFiles = os.listdir(source)

    for file in UsedFiles:
        shutil.move(source+file, archive)

source = 'C:\\Users\\FolderB\\'
FileMove(source)
```

Comment: sorry, yes that's meant to be source